# Equation numbers of different types within a same document

Tags: labels

I want to display the equation as (1) , (2), (3) and so on...... for one set of equations (section) and then I want to display the other set of equation (in another section) as (a), (b), (c), ...... and so on..... Is it possible to show both on the same document ?

In fact, I have a big document and I want to derive the expressions for different problems and for each problem or probably within one section I want to start from (1) , (2)..... and so on and on next section I again want to start the equations from (1), (2) and so on .

Please let me know if it is possible.

A sample equation is given as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 \bar{c}}{dx^2} - \frac{U}{D}\frac{d \bar{c}}{dx}- \frac{(p+K)\bar{c}}{D}=0
\end{equation}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset the equation counter

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

at the beginning of each section.

Alternatively, you can use the `amsmath` package and the command

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Answer (score 4):

At the start of one section you can go

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand\theequation{\alph{equation}}
```

and in another

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}
```